# Interpreting pts_time in FFmpeg

Tags: ffmpeg

I have been learning ffmepg for a couple of days.
I'm struggling to understand how pts or dts works.

This is the command I entered

> ffprobe -show_entries packet -read_intervals 10%+#3 Input

```
   Stream #0:0: Video: h264 (High 10), yuv420p10le(tv, bt709, progressive), 1920x1080 [SAR 1:1 DAR 16:9], 23.98 fps, 23.98 tbr, 1k tbn, 47.95 tbc (default)
Metadata:
  DURATION        : 00:02:00.203000000
Stream #0:1: Audio: flac, 48000 Hz, stereo, s16 (default)
Metadata:
  DURATION        : 00:02:00.062000000
[PACKET]
codec_type=video
stream_index=0
pts=6506
pts_time=6.506000
dts=N/A
dts_time=N/A
duration=41
duration_time=0.041000
convergence_duration=N/A
convergence_duration_time=N/A
size=205369
pos=9510964
flags=K_
[/PACKET]
```

I guess duration_time 0.041000 means the frame last(show) for 0.041 second.

I don't know how to interpret this 'pts_time' as normal time like minutes and seconds( e.g 1 min 3 second )

I set the intervals 10%+=3, which means 3 packets after 10 seconds. I can't find the relation between 10 second and pts_time=6.506000

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`pts_time=6.506000` means an absolute presentation timestamp of 6.506 seconds. It's relative presentation time depends on the start_time of the file, for which use `-show_entries format=start_time`.

ffprobe seeks to keyframes, so it will seek to the nearest KF *at or before* the specified time and then print info for the stated number of packets.

Comment: IIRC, flags=k means key frame, right? I ran the command again with -read_intervals 10%+#6. There are key frames with pts_time=6.548, 6.571...Which is closer to 10 sec. or am I mistaken, flags=k doesn't mean key frame? I can upload the result of the command if you need.

Comment: Don't consider audio packets.

Comment: You're right, those are audio packets. so is it safe to guess that pts_time represents seconds, regardless of tbn value?

Comment: Yes. pts_time is always in seconds; pts always in multiples of time base.